# React, redux and routing

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router

I've done a simple app with some CRUD actions, using component state, firebase and react routing. Now I'm trying to integrate react-redux. I've got the data logic, but I'm lacking something about routing.

Now I'm navigating through Link or redirect in the component. Should I change this? Should it be the reducer doing the navigation? Instead of a link, should I dispatch an action "navigate-to" and do the redirect in the reducer? Or is fine add an onClick on the Link and dispatch actions only for the data logic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest to keep application state and routing separate. As suggested in the  [redux documentation](https://redux.js.org/advanced/usage-with-react-router):

> So you want to do routing with your Redux app. You can use it with React Router. Redux will be the source of truth for your data and React Router will be the source of truth for your URL. In most of the cases, it is fine to have them separate unless you need to time travel and rewind actions that trigger a URL change.